# Android Gallery Performance Best Practice

Tags: android, xml, android-gallery

I was thinking about starting a gallery app with the ability to search/filter images based on tags. My question:

I want to update the images often so... should I host the images on a webserver and host a XML file the app can call with image paths thumbnail path and tags name. That way I can load the thumbs to save bandwidth until they click and then load the main image.

XML Below:

```
   <image>
      <title>My Family</title>
      <tags>family,vacation,grandpa</tags>
      <thumb>myimage_thm.jpg</thumb>
      <full_path>myimage.jpg</full_path>
    </image>
```

And then use the built in android gallery?

Does this sound like the most efficient way start my project? Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use json instead of xml format to transfer your updates.
2. Implement REST interface to post updates to your server.
3. If you are going to download these thumbnails use Async threads to download these images. Take a look at droidfu (http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/)

Also look at the app photostream by romain guy. This should give you a good idea on how to implement your gallery app.

Comment: Not sure if I understand how the json data would be created. Would I do a call to a database that returns json data? Thanks.

Comment: The data you receive from database needs be converted to json format. you will use json_encode in php. you should have something similar in other environments as well.

Comment: Since I haven't researched the data call yet...(I am just guessing) But would the app call a php page using http, the php does all the database call. Then encodes the data into json and then returns it to the app. Am I on the right track?

Comment: yes correct. search for rest client for android you will see lots of examples on how to make async rest call to your server and also how to setup your rest api on the server side.